# How to Send value from google chart in url through ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, laravel, charts, google-visualization

**want to send topping variable in url** through **ajax** 
 and i am using **laravel** **framework**

```
        function selectHandler() {
            var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
            if (selectedItem) {
                var value = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, selectedItem.column);
                var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                var columnLabel = data.getColumnLabel(selectedItem.column)
                // alert('The user selected ' + columnLabel + ': ' + topping + ' - ' + value);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/datesalesbarchartdata/" + topping,
                    dataType: 'json',

                });


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

to pass on the url, use `"GET"` request...

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/datesalesbarchartdata?topping=" + topping,
  dataType: 'json',
});
```

for `"POST"`, use the `data` key...

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/datesalesbarchartdata/",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    topping: topping
  }
});
```

Comment: @ WhiteHat Thanks for help....but later if switch type to  "Get" and my code work....           $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "{{ url('/datesalesbarchartdata') }}/" + topping,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            loadPieChart(data);
                            $('#donut_single').show();
                            $('#container').hide();
                        }
                    });